# Best way to initialize a method one time in spring , when application starts?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

I am having one method and it contains some business logic like , creating the protocols using some domain specific servers and so.I need to run the method once when my application starts.

How can I achieve my below requirement ?

This is what I have already did. I created the bean for a business class and also for controller in applicationContext.xml and inject the business class bean in the controller .

My `applicationContext.xml` will be,

```
<bean id="configInfo" class="com.pointel.Agent_Chat.ServerInfo.ConfigServerInfo">
    <property name="configurationServer_name" value="${CS_NAME}"></property>
    <property name="configurationServer_host" value="${CS_IPADDRESS}"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="config_con" class="com.pointel.Agent_Chat.ServerConnection.ConfigServerConnection" >
    <property name="info" ref="configInfo"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="init_Server" class="com.pointel.Agent_Chat.Initialiser.Initialize_Servers">
    <property name="connection" ref="config_con"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="initCon" class="com.pointel.Agent_Chat.controllers.InitServerController">
    <property name="init_Server" ref="init_Server"></property>
</bean>
```

My `Controller` will be,

```
@Controller
public class InitServerController {

    public static int count = 0;
    private Initialize_Servers init_Server;

    public InitServerController(){
        count++;
        System.out.println("Init Controller "+count+" time");
    }

    public void setInit_Server(Initialize_Servers init_Server) {
        this.init_Server = init_Server;
        initializeServers();
    }



    private void initializeServers() {
        ServerStatus.config_status = init_Server.initialize_Config_Server();
        System.out.println("config_status : "+ServerStatus.config_status);
    }

}
```

My `Business class` will be ,

```
public class Initialize_Servers {

    private ConfigServerConnection connection;
    private InteractionServerConnection interConnection;
    private UCSConnection ucsConnection;

    public Initialize_Servers(){
        System.out.println("Initialize_Servers class instance was created !");
    }

    public ConfigServerConnection getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }

    public void setConnection(ConfigServerConnection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    public boolean initialize_Config_Server(){
        try{
            ConfServerProtocol protocol = connection.getConnection();
            if(protocol != null){
                System.out.println("Config server Protocol is not null");
                return true;

            }
        }catch(Exception e){

            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Is this the right way ? or any other perfect way to do this ?

Good answers are definitely appreciated.

Comment: Did you check `ApplicationContextAware` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the bean in the xml file to have an init method using the init-method attribute on the bean XML element, like so:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="myBean" class="com.myjunk.MyBean" 
        init-method="myInit" >
    </bean>
</beans>
```

This would call the myInit() method on MyBean after the bean was initialized.  This happens after the properties were wired together.  If you are using Annotations to wire stuff, there are annotations you can use as well, but I don't know them off the top of my head.  The method must take no parameters.

The other option is to implement [ApplicationContextAware](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html), which provides hooks into getting the application context during the wiring process.  Again, this happens after the properties are set on the object.